# Dynamic binding of gridview on user selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I have a slight problem in my code.

Well, I have a gridview which basically has 8 columns, with some data, which is populated on Page_Load.

I have a textbox and a button control too.

The user enters a number (not greater than the number of columns of gridview), and clicks the button, the gridview has to hide those number of columns.

I have written a code for that, it works with certain limitations.

Below is the ASPX code:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">
        function Call() {
            window.alert('No columns to hide');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        Enter the number of columns:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="Customize" />    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the DataAccessLayer.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SampleDynamicGrid
{
public class DataAccesslayer
{
public static DataTable GetCustomizedEmployees()
        {
            SqlConnection xconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnect"].ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dbo.employee", xconn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code-behind for the webform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace SampleDynamicGrid
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = DataAccesslayer.GetCustomizedEmployees();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            DataTable dt = DataAccesslayer.GetCustomizedEmployees();
            if (number == 0)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "Call();", true);

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem which I face is: 
When the first column (the 0th index) is removed from the data table, the data table rearranges itself. 
For ex:

The original Data table

```
0th 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th

A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
```

After the 0th index column is removed, the Data Table rearranges itself to be like below:

```
0th 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th

B   C   D   E   F   G   H
```

Now **dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1**)= The 1st index column(having data C)

Similarly if the number in the text box is entered as 5,6,7, then there's an exception that

there is no column at position 4 which is quite understandable.

I know that the code is logically incorrect. Experts please advise. I want that if I write

a number (1 to 7), those number of columns should not be visible in the web form.

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Any other mechanism or logic or any other way to achieve dynamic binding of grid view will also be very welcomed.

Regards

Anurag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the 0th column each time :

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Thus you will delete the new first column each time.
You should also check that the number entered is less than 9.

Comment: Let me try your solution.Thank you

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(number);
                }

Comment: I tried the above code, if number=2, it removes 4 columns actually.May be I am not able to interpret you totally. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why do you dt.Columns.RemoveAt(number);?   
You are removing twice with this.

Comment: Ohh yeah..My bad buddy...I get it now..Thanks..What should be the correct approach if a user wants to remove any number of columns(irrespective of the order) ? I mean the gridview should be totally dynamic for him..Any thoughts??

Comment: You want him to chose which columns are removed?

Comment: Yes..i understand that I need to provide him with a list box kind of thing so that he/she is able to choose. I wana know what kind of mechanism should I follow? Any links or stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is the "Visible" attribute. try something like

```
int colmin = 1//whichever columns you want to make invisible
int colmax = 8
for (int i = colmin; i < colmax; i++)
{
    datagridview1.Columns[i].Visible = false;
}
```

This way the columns are hidden, but the indexes remain unchanged.

Hope that helps.
Cheers

Comment: I get your point, but on button click every time I need to bind the grid and then try your solution, since button click serves a postback.

Comment: datagridview1.Columns[i].Visible = false; shows IndexOutOfRange exception